# Writing Excel formula using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, worksheet-function

I want to write a formula to SUM from column B4 to M4, this should be done using vb.net programming.

I tried using the following stuff:

```
oXLWsheet.Range(4, 14).Formula = "=SUM(oXLWsheet!$B$4:M$4)" 
                                 "=SUM(B4:M4)" 
                                 "=SUM(B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,G4,H4,I4,J4,K4,L4,M4)"
```

Nothing is working for me. I'm getting the following error when I run the code:

`"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC".`

Comment: Have you tried using .Value instead of .Formula?

Comment: @miky, please use the `worksheet-function` tag for all excel formula questions.  If you have votes on it, please go vote for the `worksheet-function` synonym.  Thanks.

Comment: @Lance - sure. My edit was not really focused on the tags but actually on the text of question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try quoting the range, and if you're trying to fill two different rows you have to show each row like so:

```
oXLWsheet.Range("4:4,14:14").Formula = "=SUM(oXLWsheet!$B$4:M$4)"
```

This of course gives you a circular reference.  If you're just trying to put the values in cell N4, then use this:

```
oXLWsheet.Range("$N$4").Formula = "=SUM(oXLWsheet!$B$4:M$4)"
```

(Dollar signs optional)

Comment: thanks lance, this is not working for me. in the excel all the cell contains something like this "REF #"..

Comment: @Sun, then your formula is getting to Excel, so your first problem is solved.  If you're getting the REF error, then there's a problem with your formula itself.  Personally I'd remove the sheet reference to make it easier to figure out.

Comment: Hi Lance, can you please tell me you u added like this "4:4,14:14". I think this make the entire cell of the row (i.e. 4 ) to show as #REF!. I used the formula "=SUM(B4,M4)" ,  "=SUM(B5,C5,D5,E5,F5,G5,H5,I5,J5,K5,L5,M5)" . but nothing working :(

Comment: @Sun, You have to use quotes for a Range reference inside the Range object.  If you want to address an entire row, like your code seemed to show, then you have to do it with a colon like this: 4:4.  This addresses the entire 4th row.  The comma means that it unions the two different rows, so you are putting that formula in ALL of row 4 and row 14.  This also means that you have a circular reference, so you might want to do it differently.

Comment: @Sun, see my update if you're trying for a specific cell, or you could use the Cells syntax that Erwan mentioned.

Comment: Lance, thanks for the info, im new in working with interop objects.

Comment: @Lance, thanks a lot, its working :) If you dont mind i have one more question. i have created ONE chart(graph) using the details in the cell, actually i want to create TWO chart in the same area, Say type of the chart shld be 'Line chart' and 'AreaStacked'. If you are aware of this Can you please tell me how to do.            Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Sun, I don't specifically know how to do Charts in Interop, though I imagine you have to use the Chart or ChartObject objects.

Comment: Lance, thanks.  if i have any other query, will contact you. thanks again

Comment: @Sun, you don't need to contact me, just post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Cells instead of Range with this notation :

```
oXLWsheet.Cells(4, 14).Formula = "=SUM(oXLWsheet!$B$4:M$4)"
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, its not alloed to use this , saying ""option strict on disallow late binding"

Answer (score -1):

You have to split your statements when you are working with late binding:

```
Dim oXLRange as Excel.Range
oXLRange = CType(oXLWsheet.Cells(4, 14), Excel.Range)
oXLRange.Formula = "SUM(Q8:T9)"
```

Using the `.Formula` property you have to use the english version of the Excel formula. If you want to use the localized version of an Excel formula, use `.FormulaLocal`